# Copy & Paste items from one view to another within storyboard without referencing outlets?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, copy-paste

When I copy and paste, (cmd-c, cmd-v) items from one view to another in Storyboard it also copies and pastes the items referencing outlets.

Obviously, it's achievable by going in and deleting the referencing outlets one by one. Which is what I want to avoid.

I'm looking for something akin to (dare I say it) Excel's 'paste special' command.

## UPDATE

Nope, doesn't work in xcode 5.1 either, see image below, hopefully it succinctly shows you what is going on.

[image]

The image shows a view at the top, Add Expense View Controller, another view at the bottom, the name's beside the point, I've copied my cells from Add Expense View Controller, lo & behold it's got the old references in there. You can also see I'm using xcode 5.1...

**So - how do you, or is it simply not possible, copy and paste without these references?**

Interestingly there is a paste special option in the Edit menu, but in Xcode's menu definitions in the documentation there is no definition for "Paste Special"...

Comment: Are you using Xcode 5.1? I can't reproduce this, though I remember it was like you said.

Comment: Oh, right, I'm on 5.0.2. The latest Xcode doesn't do this any more? If you're sure about that then you can go ahead and say "Update your xcode to 5.1 or above" as an answer and I'll accept it even though, strictly speaking, that's not really doing what I asked.

Comment: This is not mission-critical for me, obviously, I am now interested in this from an academic point of view having already moved past this in my code base.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like they fixed it on `Xcode 5.1`. Both copy/paste and option+drag doesn't copy the referencing outlets.

Comment: Now I just need to find more space on my ssd. Up to 5.75 gb now but still not enough to do the update... Geez.

Comment: Oh well, bye bye Starcraft.

Comment: Get a bigger SSD and please send me the old one.

Comment: Ha, these new MacBooks don't let you swap out your SSDs! I have bootcamp on here, stupidly I thought that I'd donate half my space to my windows partition.

Comment: Sorry, had to take check mark away from this as updating to 5.1 didn't solve the problem. You'll see I've got a screen shot up above with 2 views, some copy/pasted items and even my xcode version number in there.

Comment: I want copy WITH reference outlet in Xcode 7.1. How can I do it?